# spock: need a hook to perform some setup steps before any test class executes

Tags: junit, spock

I have several Spock test classes grouped together in a package. I am using Junit 4.10. Each test class contains several feature test methods.

I want to perform some setup steps (such as loading data into a DB, starting up a web server) before I run any test case, but only once when the testing starts.

I want this "OneTimeSetup" method to be called only once whether:

- I run all the test classes in the package (for example if they are grouped in a Test Suite)
- I run a few test classes
- I run only one test class
- I run only a certain feature method within a test class

From reading other posts on SO, it seems that this is what TestNG's @BeforeSuite does.

I am aware of Spock's setupSpec() and cleanupSpec() methods, but they only work within a given test class. I am looking to do something like "setupTestSuite()." How can this be achieved in Spock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a global extension, use a JUnit test suite, call a static method in a helper class (say from `setupSpec`) that does its work just once, or let the build tool do the job.